# Is there a ubuntu meta-package for the mono command line tools and ASP.NET tools?

Tags: command-line, application-development, mono

I've discovered that if I install MonoDevelop on ubuntu, and then I decide to install something from the command line I need to add the following packages:

```
apt-get install xbuild mono-gmcs
```

If I need to run an ASP.NET project:

```
apt-get install mono-xsp4
```

Finally, to run unit tests from the command line I need to do the following:

```
apt-get install nunit-console
```

I can keep a list of all these packages and install them with one command line. However, I would expect that if they aren't installed as MonoDevelop dependencies, they would be included in some sort of mono-devel-cmdline package. Does such a package exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best package available for your request is `mono-complete` which has the

> complete Mono runtime, development tools and all libraries

according to the [Ubuntu package listings](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mono-complete). This is for Precise, so if you are running an earlier version I should check out the equivalent at Ubuntu packages.

Running the command

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

will install what you do not have already.

However, although this is arguably the best package available it may not install everything you want, but will certainly allow you to enter fewer commands to get `mono` set up.

Comment: This is somewhat useful, but doesn't give you xbuild or mono-xsp even. I guess this is the best I can do.